# Video clip making features with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, audio, windows-movie-maker

I'm trying to use `ffmpeg` to create a video clip out of multiple videos, photos, and background music. Basically all the features that tools like `Windows Movie Maker` support. I would like to do things like:

- merge the videos with arbitrary start/ends,
- add transition effects between them,
- add background music,
- fade-in/fade-out/mute/stop music at certain time periods,
- and more...

Can I do these with `ffmpeg`? Or is there any APIs in either `Python` or `Java` that I can easily use to do that?

Comment: All of these can be done - see trim, fade, volume, concat, blend, amix, filters.. etc. Support for transition effects is limited, though.

Comment: @Gyan That looks like an answer to me!  Please post one and ping me and I'll come back and upvote!  **0:-)**

Comment: @gyan would be great if you could post an example of each just for the sake of answer.

Comment: There are examples of each question scattered about on [so], [su], and here.